# Discrete Uniform Probability: isn't my textbook just wrong?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, economics

My textbook is showing me examples of discrete probability distributions, one of them is in the picture:

[image: Snippet of my textbook]

I learned in Calculus that the summation of the series $1/n$ where $n\to \infty$ is divergent. Yet this text says that it converges at $1$.

I also think that the example is bad but I'll stay on topic.

Comment: $n$ doesn't go to $\infty$ here, it goes from $1$ to $6$!!!

Comment: And there is nothing wrong with the example BTW (if you think otherwise, then you should specify exactly what it is).

Comment: In the example it goes from 1/6 but not the general form. Besides 1/N where N goes from1-6 does not provide a series whose summation is 1. Edit: and the example seems wrong because Pr(X=1) =/= Pr(X=6) because if X = x = 1 then 1/N = 1/1 = 1 not 1/6.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion in you question and in your comments: the text says $f(x)$ is null everywhere except than at the $N$ mass points, so you will never add an infinite number of terms, but always $N$ terms so that $N\cdot {1\over N}=1$. Also in your comment $X=x=1$ makes no sense... when you sample from a random distribution (in this case discrete uniform with parameters N) you don't change the properties of the distribution: in your example $N=6$ for both samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your textbook isn't wrong. $N$ is a fixed number (6 in the example), so the sum is over a finite number of terms, which is perfectly ok.

Besides, the sum isn't the harmonic series... It is $$\frac{1}{N}+ \frac{1}{N}+ ... + \frac{1}{N}$$ where there are $N$ summands. So in the example $$ \frac{1}{6}+  \frac{1}{6}+  \frac{1}{6}+  \frac{1}{6}+  \frac{1}{6}+  \frac{1}{6}=1$$

Comment: But can we still say that the summation from x =1 to x=6 of 1/x =1? I mean I must be missing something obvious because I believe you but I can't come to terms with this.

Comment: Yes, you are: the function is $f(\mathbf{x})=1/\mathbf{N}$. Note the change of letters